# Disabling fancyhead in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer

## Question

The header **Bibliography** appears on both of the right and the left sides of the second page of my bibliography. How to make the header appear only on one side (left or right)?
[image]

## Description

In my preamble, I have

```tex
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\newcommand{\changefont}{\fontsize{10}{11}\selectfont}
\fancyhead[L]{\changefont \slshape \nouppercase \rightmark} %section
\fancyhead[R]{\changefont \slshape \nouppercase \leftmark} %chapter
\setlength{\headheight}{12.5pt}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

Comment: Please provide a small complete document (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document`, including bibliography entries) that illustrates your problem. Without knowing the details of your setup it is not really possible to give advice.

Comment: Does the following answer help? [https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/164651](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/164651/110998)

Comment: @gernot `\fancyhead[L]{}` before `\bibliography{Bibliography}` solved the problem. I can accept your answer.